# Large hat pushes the profile and activity tabs to the right

Tags: bug, profile-page, winter-bash-2015, profile-picture

I don't know if this behavior is intentional, but it looks kinda funny to me that the Profile and Activity tabs are moving when you switch from the Profile tab to the Activity tab and vice versa. This only happens when you wear a large hat.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without the obligatory freehand red circles it's really hard to see what the issue is <g>

Comment: @JonClements My bad. I'll correct my error :)

Comment: @JonClements I hope that's sufficient :). An animated git might have been better though, but that's too much for me.